# Joining 2 lines into 1 line that have different patterns

Tags: bash

```
Time: 07:15:08 AM

class1: A B C D E
class2: F G H
Class3: I J K
Class4: L M N


Time:07:15:11 AM

class1: a b c d e
class2: f g h
Class3: i j k
Class4: l m n
```

I have the above data in a text file. I have to combine the 2 lines like this

```
Time: 07:15:08 AM Class3: I J K
Time:07:15:11 AM  Class3: i j k
```

In a bash shell . Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You could try the awk command,

```
$ awk '/^(Time:|[Cc]lass3:)/' file | paste - -
Time: 07:15:08 AM   Class3: I J K
Time:07:15:11 AM    Class3: i j k
```